# Number of injective homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many injective homomorphisms exist from group $\mathbb{Z}_3(+)$ to group $S_4(\circ)$?

Comment: Hi: in the future, to get the best answers and hints fastest, it's always a good idea to post the work you've done so far. People are more eager to help you if they see you're actually spending efforts on the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint that is too long for a comment : An injective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to any group is equivalent to an element of that group of order 3.

In $S_n$, your life is made easier by the cycle decomposition. If you write an element $\sigma \in S_n$ as a product of disjoint cycles, its order is the lcm of the orders of those cycles. Hence, an element of order 3 in $S_n$ is merely a 3-cycle.

So, your question boils down to asking : How many 3-cycles does $S_4$ have?

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* Any homomorphism $f\colon \mathbb Z_3\to G$ is uniquely determined by specifying $f(1)$, which must be an element of order dividing $3$ (and for injective: of order exactly $3$).